Flutter: Tabbarview and fullscreen errors
My main screen is Tabbarview. I have different error states, and need to implement different UI for each. What is the best approach to deal with this if I only want one instance of Tabbarview, but need to have errors shown like this:

State1 Error: show specific error inside individual tab content
State2 Error: show error pop-up on top of Tabbarview, but hide tab content
State3 error: show generic error on all tabs
State4 error: show error fullscreen


Here is how I will do it.
I will create an enum to group the definition of all error cases.
enum ErrorState {
  state1, 
  state2, 
  state3, 
  state4, 
  none,
}

I will add the variable to track the error state in my StatefulWidget
class MyScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyScreenState createState() => _MyScreenState();
}

class _MyScreenState extends State<MyScreen> {
  ErrorState _errorState = ErrorState.none;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
  }
}

And I will implement the display of errors in separate functions
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  switch (_errorState) {
      case ErrorState.state1:
        return _buildUiOfErrorState1();
      case ErrorState.state2:
        return _buildUiOfErrorState2();
      case ErrorState.state3:
        return _buildUiOfErrorState3();
      case ErrorState.state4:
        return _buildUiOfErrorState4();
      default:
        return _buildNormalUI();
    }
}

Widget _buildUiOfErrorState1() {
}

Widget _buildUiOfErrorState2() {
}

Widget _buildUiOfErrorState3() {
}

Widget _buildUiOfErrorState4() {
}

This approach allows you to keep a single instance of TabBarView and manage the display according to different possible error states.
